# Add-Type cannot find file

Tags: powershell

Trying to `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` fails with:

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Using clean installation of Windows Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

After doing some experimentation, I have used Add features wizard in Server manager and added .NET Framework 3.5.1. After this all works well. I wonder why installing latest .NET framework (4.5.2) did not help.

Comment: This is late but I think someone might get benefited with the answer. You are correct @Wlodek, it will work after installing .NET Framework 3.5.1 because - if something is developed using a specific version of .Net, it requires that version of .Net to function - higher version of .Net won't provide that backward compatibility. Thus having .NET framework (4.5.2) will obviously not help.